# What are proper scopes for API requests

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to give permission for one application to access some data from another account. I do OAuth2 authentication, but in the v2.0 we need to pass not resources, but scopes. For example I want to start/stop VirtualMachines, or just List them, what would be the proper scope for this?

I have found just this reference but I guess it is not valid for new flow `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftaad`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are signing in as yourself (i.e. with a signed-in user), then the `scope` value you want to request is `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`. After signing in (and granting consent, if needed), access to Azure resources will be dependent on the permissions the signed-in user.

If instead this is a secure server doing unattended access, then you simply use the "place-holder" scope parameter value `https://management.azure.com/.default` (as a way of indicating that you want an access token to `https://management.azure.com`).

Comment: Thank you for the response, when I add this `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` to scope it refuses me to connect with my personal account. But I have this setting `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",` in my manifest file. Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: Azure always relies on Azure AD (organizational accounts). Your personal account is most likely present in an Azure AD tenant (directory) as an external user. So, though this may seem counter-intuitive, try using the ["organizations" endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints) (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/...`).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Philippe. I appreciate it